# Uploaded wsdl size exceeded the maximum upload limit

Tags: apex, wsdl

I can not generate apex code after parsing any of the WSDL file.

I am facing error: **Uploaded WSDL size exceeded the maximum upload limit: {0}**

parsing enterprise WSDL file have size is 1.5 MB.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. Manually extract the elements from the WSDL that you don't need and then send that through WSDL2Apex. It will generate less Apex code.
2. Use the Partner API rather than the Enterprise API. The WSDL is smaller as it doesn't have dedicated complex types for every object in your org.
3. Use the version of WSDL2Apex in the [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclaimer - this is a free tool from my current employer). After you import the WSDL you will be given an option to select the web menthods you need access to. You can then opt to comment out or exclude and unnessacary parts of the code not required by the selected methods.